# With regex, how to match misused blankspace inside tab indent

Tags: regular-expression, greedy-mode

Say the line is:

`^<space1><space2><tab1><tab2><space3><space4><tab3><tab4><space5><space6><tab5><tab6><space7><space8>blablabla`

So how to match all these `<space>`?

(FYI, I use `call matchadd("yqi_faulty_indent", '<THE_REGEX>')` to highlight it)

- With `^\t*\zs\ \+`, it matches only `<space1><space2>`
- With `^\s*\zs\ \+`, it matches only `<space7><space8>` due to the greedy mode I think
- With `^\s\{-}\zs\ \+`, it matches only `<space1><space2>` due to the non-greedy mode I think
- With `\v((^\s*)@<= +)`, it matches what I want, BUT, with lookaround regex, there's unacceptable high CPU when there are long lines like `seq 1 30000 | tr '\n' ' ' | fold -w 3000 | vim -`

**UPDATE**

According to the important hint from Vivian's answer, below is my latest solution:

- `call matchadd("yqi_faulty_indent", '\v((^\s*)@80<= +)')` highlights blankspaces in TAB indent
- `call matchadd("yqi_faulty_indent", '\v((^\s*)@80<=\t+)')` highlights TABs in blankspace indent

While as mentioned in comment, there's size  limitation, looking forwards furthur better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
/\v((^\s*\t)@<= +|(^\s*)@<= +\t@=)/
```

For performance reason you could do (limiting the lookahead to 80 bytes):

```
/\v((^\s*\t)@80<= +|(^\s*)@80<= +\t@=)/
```

Comment: This also matches blanks in the middle of a line which isn't expected, not only the indent part

Comment: You are right :-) I have improved the pattern accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I use lookaround regex before, however it causes high CPU, please see my update, so I have to switch to \zs. Looking forward better solution

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: I'm somehow surprised by the performance problem. Unless you have lines that start with a very large number of white spaces the lookhead operator should not get lost. Otherwise you can also limit the lookhead (I have updated my solution).

Comment: It's the best solution so far, while currently I have another shorter one \v((^\s*)@80<= +), seems also meet my requirement as I tried some cases, would you check if there's any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: In general look-behind should be avoided, and in this case it's certainly not needed, since you can simply anchor to the start of line and then mark the start-of-replacement with `\zs` (see my separate answer).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt if you're editing a file with 10M lines in it, you'll certainly notice how badly look-behind performs.

Answer (score 0):

I would just search for `^\t*\zs \+\ze\t`

This avoids a performance-killing look-behind: match any number of leading tabs, then at least one space, then at least one more tab.

The run of space characters are wrapped with start-of-replacement `\zs` and end-of-replacement `\ze`, so that you can use this inside a `s///` to remove or replace just the space characters.

If you're wanting a pattern to use in syntax highlighting, you'd want to anchor at both start-of-line and end-of-previous-match: `\%(^\|\zG\)\t*\zs \+\ze\t`. Unfortunately `\zG` is not be available in all versions of Vim. (It's the equivalent of Perl's `\G`.)

If you don't have that then perhaps it would be acceptable simply to highlight all whitespace between the first and last misused spaces:

```
syntax match BadSpace "^\t*\zs \%(\s* \)\=\ze\t"
highlight BadSpace term=inverse gui=inverse
```

However if replacement is your intention, I suggest using the `:retab` command instead.

If you really want to search for any blanks rather than just ASCII space, then it gets slightly more complicated: `^\t*[^\t]\@=\s\+\t`

The key is a single-character that simultaneously matches not-a-tab *and* matches blank.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but as I tried ^\t*\zs \+\ze\t only highlights the first occurence

Comment: I have to admit, I was assuming this would be used in some kind of search-and-replace, and so multiple occurrences in one line would be handled in turn.